# How to scrape all text inside all p tags including the text in span?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
table = soup.findAll('div', attrs={"class":"five columns"})
for data in table:
    para = data.findAll('p')
    print para
```

This is what I still am left with.

```
<p><span class="four">Location: </span> <span id="wt-loc" title="New Delhi / Safdarjung">New Delhi / Safdarjung</span></p>, <p><span class="four">Current Time: </span> <span id="wtct">Feb 12, 2017 at 10:29:52 am</span></p>, <p><span class="four">Latest Report: </span> Feb 12, 2017 at 8:30 am</p>, <p><span class="four">Visibility: </span> 1 km</p>, <p><span class="four">Pressure: </span> 102.12 kPa</p>, <p><span class="four">Humidity: </span> 95%</p>, <p><span class="four">Dew Point: </span> 10 °C</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `.text` attribute of the BeautifulSoup object `para.text`. I further splitted the keypair values with `re.split()` function, if you don't want to split, then just do `para.text`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

a = """<p><span class="four">Location: </span> <span id="wt-loc" title="New Delhi / Safdarjung">New Delhi / Safdarjung</span></p>, <p><span class="four">Current Time: </span> <span id="wtct">Feb 12, 2017 at 10:29:52 am</span></p>, <p><span class="four">Latest Report: </span> Feb 12, 2017 at 8:30 am</p>, <p><span class="four">Visibility: </span> 1 km</p>, <p><span class="four">Pressure: </span> 102.12 kPa</p>, <p><span class="four">Humidity: </span> 95%</p>, <p><span class="four">Dew Point: </span> 10 °C</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(a, 'html.parser')
re.split(r', (?=\s*[A-Z])', soup.text)
```

Output:

```
[u'Location:  New Delhi / Safdarjung',
 u'Current Time:  Feb 12, 2017 at 10:29:52 am',
 u'Latest Report:  Feb 12, 2017 at 8:30 am',
 u'Visibility:  1 km',
 u'Pressure:  102.12 kPa',
 u'Humidity:  95%',
 u'Dew Point:  10 \uc9f8C']
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.text` to get all the text under p tag, what you need to do is iterate over the `findAll(p)`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<p><span class="four">Location: </span> <span id="wt-loc" title="New Delhi / Safdarjung">New Delhi / Safdarjung</span></p>, <p><span class="four">Current Time: </span> <span id="wtct">Feb 12, 2017 at 10:29:52 am</span></p>, <p><span class="four">Latest Report: </span> Feb 12, 2017 at 8:30 am</p>, <p><span class="four">Visibility: </span> 1 km</p>, <p><span class="four">Pressure: </span> 102.12 kPa</p>, <p><span class="four">Humidity: </span> 95%</p>, <p><span class="four">Dew Point: </span> 10 °C</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(p.text)
```

out:

```
Location:  New Delhi / Safdarjung
Current Time:  Feb 12, 2017 at 10:29:52 am
Latest Report:  Feb 12, 2017 at 8:30 am
Visibility:  1 km
Pressure:  102.12 kPa
Humidity:  95%
Dew Point:  10 °C
```

Answer (score 0):

Beautiful soup has a function called [get_text()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) that allows you to get all text within a tag ignoring other tags.  Just call `p.get_text()`.  If you also want to remove the white space call `p.get_text(strip=True)`.